# An inequality from entropy

Tags: inequality

Is there an easy way to show $p2^{1-p}\leq1$ if $p\in[0,1]$?

Is there a direct way to see this inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way, using Bernoulli's inequality and AM-GM:
$$p(1+1)^{1-p}\le p(1+1-p) \le 1$$

Comment: How did you get $(1+1)^{1-p}\leq(1+1-p)$?

Comment: That's Bernoulli's inequality for exponent in $(0,1)$. Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality for eg.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easy enough:

$$\frac{d}{dp}(p2^{1-p})=2^{1-p}(1-p\ln 2)>0,$$

which is positive for $0\leq p\leq 1$ and so the expression is maximized for $p=1$, where it is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to prove that $$ 2^p-2p\ge 0,\quad p\in[0,1].$$

You have $2^1-2\cdot 1=0$, so the inequality holds for $p=1$.

The function $p\to 2^p$ is convex, hence its graph is above the tangent line at point $p=1$. The equation of this tangent is $y = 2\ln 2 (p-1)+2$. The slope of this tangent is hence given by $2\ln2$. The slope of the line $p\to 2p$ is $2$.

Given that $2\ln2<2 $, the tangent line has a less steep slope than the line $p\to 2p$, therefore, $$\forall p\le 1 \quad 2^p\ge 2\ln2 (p-1)+2\ge 2p $$